# How to align macros to correct order in TikZ matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, matrices

How to fix the broken placement of macros in matrix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\macroA}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=1.5cm, draw, rectangle] at (0,0) {PI};
\draw (0.2,-0.75)--(0.75,0)--(0.2,0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\macroB}[1]
{       
        \tikz[baseline,inner sep=1pt]
        {
                \node[draw,shape=circle] {#1};
                }
}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[auto,
block/.style ={rectangle, draw, thick,text centered, minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=1.4cm}]
\matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
{
% row 1
\node [block](a) {a}; &
\node [block](b) {b}; &
\node [block](c) {c}; \\
% row 2
\node [block](d) {d}; & \\
% row 3
\node [block](e) {e}; &
\node [block](f) {f}; & \\
% row 4
\node [block](g) {g}; & \\
% row 5
\node [block](h) {h}; & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]
{
% row 1
\macroA &
\macroB{X} &
\macroA \\
% row 2
\macroA;  & \\
% row 3
\macroB{X} &
\macroB{X}  & \\
% row 4
\macroB{X}  & \\
% row 5
\macroB{X}  & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{pinode/.code={
\pgfset{inner sep=7.5mm}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{base}{PI}{x}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{2mm}{0}}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{north}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{x}{east}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{2mm}{0}}{\pgfpointanchor{x}{south}}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
}

\newcommand{\macroA}{|[pinode]|}
\newcommand{\macroB}[1]{|[draw,circle]|#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,block/.style ={
                                        rectangle, 
                                        draw, 
                                        thick,
                                        text centered, 
                                        minimum height=0.7cm,
                                        minimum width=1.4cm,
                                        inner sep=0,
                                        outer sep=0,anchor=center
                                        }
                                        ]
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={block},
                column sep=5mm,
                row sep=7mm]
{
% row 1
a&b&c\\    % row 2
d& & \\    % row 3
e&f& \\    % row 4
g& & \\    % row 5
h& &\\    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]
{
% row 1
\macroA &\macroB{X} &\macroA \\    % row 2
\macroA & & \\    % row 3
\macroB{X}&\macroB{X}  & \\    % row 4
\macroB{X}  & &\\    % row 5
\macroB{X}  & &\\    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** In case anyone is interested, after our chat session, we were able to define a new shape for the `pinode` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{pinode}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\backgroundpath{%
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
\northeast \pgf@xa=0\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y \pgf@xb=\pgf@x
\southwest \pgf@yc = \pgf@y
\advance \pgf@xa by .9\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
\advance \pgf@yb by .5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[opacity=0.2,style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (5cm,5cm);
\node [draw,pinode,inner sep=5mm] (a) at (0,2) {PI};
\node [draw,pinode,inner sep=5mm] (b) at (4,5) {PI};
\draw[->,thick] (a.east)-| ++ (1cm,1cm) |- (b.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, thank you :). As I see, I have to dig the pgf code due I'm trying solve all problems just with TikZ macros of pgf code.

Comment: No problem, it's actually not that different than what you have done. I only took out the extra `tikzpicture` and `\tikz` environments and made the declarations more local.

Comment: If you don't mind and have some time I would like show you and get you into my complete problem what I need to finish in LaTeX - wont post it here as problem/question coz it will not meet the minimal requirements. If you agree or anybody else just contact me on gmail - jezkovivocihorimpreboha@gmail.com . Will appreciate much.

Comment: I can't promise to spare too much time but if it is like an image or similar, you can upload it on imgur and post it on the chat. Make sure to put @percusse in the beginning of your message to ping me when you are done. Then others and I can try to have a look at it. Or if it can be isolated you can keep asking concrete and specialized questions. We are here to help anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but can't post anything right now on the chat - 2 points needed and you know ehm..I wont look like some annoying dumb person. :\ And I prefer kind of communication what lefts history,closer chats, because it's important work what I need to be done for my university.

Comment: I have capped the vote limit so I can vote later for your other question and get a chat room for us :)

Comment: Normally I would have no problem wait.. just the time ins't a good fella. But i will :) if I have no other choice. You've got the mail there so if something.. I can define the problem anytime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2748/discussion-between-percusse-and-berso)